# Optimize sql query update in MySQL 5.5.62 version

Tags: mysql

I working with MySql RDBMS

```
mysql> SELECT VERSION();
+------------------+
| VERSION()        |
+------------------+
| 5.5.62           |
+------------------+
1 row in set
```

On my MySql RDBMS I have two tables

1. `tbl_old`, number of rows 745.088
2. `tbl_new`, number of rows 115.127

I need update on `tbl_new` the column `cod_New` with the value on `tbl_old` from column `cod_Old`

I have tried this SQL query but is very long time on execute

```
UPDATE `tbl_new` jjj,
 `tbl_old` kkk
SET jjj.`cod_New` = kkk.`cod_Old`
WHERE
    jjj.`COD_ORG_NEW` = kkk.`COD_ORG_OLD`
AND CASE
WHEN jjj.`TYPE_2` = 'SC' THEN
    cod_series = 2
WHEN jjj.`TYPE_2` = 'SP' THEN
    cod_series = 3
ELSE
    cod_series = 4
END
AND jjj.`element_New` = kkk.`element_Old`;
```

inserting indexes of the columns involved on the two tables don't change the situation

how to optimize this query execution?

thank you in advance for any help

**update**

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_new` (
  `COD_ORG_NEW` char(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `element_New` char(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cod_New` char(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `TYPE_2` char(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`sID`),
  KEY `COD_ORG_NEW` (`COD_ORG_NEW`),
  KEY `element_New` (`element_New`),
  KEY `cod_New` (`cod_New`),
  KEY `TYPE_2` (`TYPE_2`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=115128 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;



CREATE TABLE `tbl_old` (
  `COD_ORG_Old` char(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cod_Old` char(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cod_series` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `element_Old` char(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`sID`),
  KEY `COD_ORG_Old` (`COD_ORG_Old`),
  KEY `cod_Old` (`cod_Old`),
  KEY `cod_series` (`cod_series`),
  KEY `element_Old` (`element_Old`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=745089 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: I would normalise the schema. In a normalised environment, this particular case statement would not be necessary. That said, I doubt it has much impact on performance.

Comment: @Strawberry thanks but the schema is normalised

Comment: Plainly, that's not true. Anyway, presumably, you have composite indexes on  `tbl_new (cod_org_new,element_new,type2,cod_series)` and `tbl_old (cod_org_old,element_old)`

Comment: @Strawberry yes i have these indexes, but what do you mean? composite indexes? I have tried without case statements in WHERE clause, the situation don’t change, the execution of the query is very long time and I have to stopping the query

the problem is elsewhere

Comment: Drop all indexes except for your primary keys and instead create indexes on (cod_org_new,element_new,type2,cod_series) and (cod_org_old,element_old)

Comment: Then show us the EXPLAIN for your query

Comment: I had a similar problem when using tables with different charsets. Perhaps that's the issue here too, because you have old and new table?

Comment: @Strawberry please see last **update** in my first question

Comment: @ClausBönnhoff please see last **update** in my first question

Comment: There's no EXPLAIN here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I had in mind:

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_new` (
  `COD_ORG_NEW` char(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `element_New` char(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cod_New` char(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `TYPE_2` char(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sID` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`sID`),
  KEY (cod_org_new,element_new,type2) 
) ENGINE=InnoDB;



CREATE TABLE `tbl_old` (
  `COD_ORG_Old` char(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cod_Old` char(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cod_series` int  DEFAULT NULL,
  `element_Old` char(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sID` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`sID`),
  KEY (cod_org_old,element_old,cod_series)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Or some variation of those indexes.